# Zip into separate files

Tags: file-management, zip

I need to separate a huge directory into multiple .zip files that are not interdependent on each other.  So, instead of:

- file1.zip
- file2.z01
- file3.z02

I would like the following set of files instead:

- file1.zip
- file2.zip
- file3.zip

I wish to open each .zip file separately.  Preferably I could state a maximum file size of 2GB per file that each of these .zip files will not exceed.

Anyone have a good idea?

Comment: what os? there's a few tools good for this for *nix based systems like dirsplit.

Comment: mac and windows. This should be a relatively simple operation as it would be used by non power users.

Comment: would anyone give a more power user option?

Answer (score 4):

My technique for this is not tools based, but very simple (apologies if you are looking for a tool)

1. select files in the folder until the total size is almost 2GB
2. right-click for context menu
3. add to zip file
4. name (file1.zip, file2.zip etc)
5. repeat until all files in folder are zipped

Comment: I think it's good, that sounds like the "non power user" option :p