# How to zip multiple files into separate archives?

Tags: macos, terminal, shell, zip, applescript

I admit this question was asked here before:

Like [Zip into separate files](https://superuser.com/questions/281161/zip-into-separate-files) where the person who asked didn't specify the OS he used and received no answers.

> I need to separate a huge directory into multiple .zip files that are not interdependent on each other. So, instead of:
>
> file1.zip
>   file2.z01
>   file3.z02
>
> I would like the following set of files instead:
>
> file1.zip
>   file2.zip
>   file3.zip

Basically this is my question. I'm on OS X so a shell script or AppleScript would be the easiest way to go.

In addition, here is a guy who asked the same thing - only he wanted to create a .tar archive: How to [Creating separate archives for a set of files](https://superuser.com/questions/390602/creating-separate-archives-for-a-set-of-files)

The answer is correct, but it will result in tar files:

```
for file in `ls *`; do tar -czvf $file.tar.gz $file ; done
```

---

PS: This last part is just for those of you who are fit in Keyboard Maestro:

I also tried to perform this in Keyboard Maestro, I have a "for each" action setup which determines the file paths and then triggers a shell script. The output is correct and the macro works if I paste it in the terminal (e.g. `zip 
/Users/me/Desktop/test /Users/me/Desktop/test.txt`).

However, when I pass the two variables to the shell script in Keyboard Maestro won't work:
`zip "$KMVAR_zipPath" "$KMVAR_sourcePath"`

Comment: Well, have you tried replacing `tar -czvf` with `zip` in the `tar` solution?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is pretty easy. If you want to do this for every file, recursively, use `find`. It will list all files and directories, descending into subdirectories too.

```
find . -type f -execdir zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

Explanation:

- The first argument is the directory you want to begin in, `.`
- Then we will restrict it to find files only (`-type f`)
- The `-execdir` option allows us to run a command on each file found, executing it from the file's directory
- This command is evaluated as `zip file.txt.zip file.txt`, for example, since all occurrences of `{}` are replaced with the actual file name. This command needs to be ended with `\;`

---

Of course, `find` has more options. If instead you just want to stay in your current directory, not descending into subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -execdir zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

If you want to restrict it to certain file types, use the `-name` option (or `-iname` for case-insensitive matching):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" …
```

Anything else (including looping with `for` over the output of `ls *`) is pretty ugly syntax in my opinion and likely to break, e.g. on files with spaces in their name or due to too many arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work here.

Output when paste the recursive one: http://cl.ly/Gzbh --- 

I wouldn't mind specifying the files to zip by extension if that makes it easier.

Comment: Oops, see my update. `zip` needs an extension if the files have one. For files without an extension it'll automatically append .zip

Comment: Nice, it works splendid. Thank you very much. --- For the bonus points: would you mind telling me how to do this for a certain file type, c.f. with the extension ".txt"? I tried some variants but…

Comment: See my second update. Check the manpage of `find`, everything's explained pretty nicely, and if you haven't really used it before, it's probably one of the most useful tools on a *nix system.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm looking to the "man find" and it's really seems like a big useful tool.

Comment: And if you'd like to zip a folder full of other folders, making each subfolder its own ZIP file, you'd use the following syntax: find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -execdir zip -r '{}.zip' '{}' \; The key changes here are "-type d" to specify directories, and "-r", which will cause zip to recursively archive folder contents. In Terminal, make sure you're current working directory is the parent of the child folders.