# Recursively zip all files in a directory into individual zip files... but in a separate directory

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, zip

Similar questions have been asked, but I couldn't find exactly what I'm looking for. Basically, I have a large directory with subdirectories and many files, and I want to go into each directory and subdirectory recursively, and zip each file individually. I found this solution, but it's not quite what I want:

```
find . -type f -execdir zip '{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/430388/how-to-zip-multiple-files-into-separate-archives)

This outputs the zip files into the directory they came from. However, I want the zip files in a completely separate directory, but with the same directory structure, with only the resulting zip files. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You can cp -r the directory containing all the directories and file somewhere. Then you delete all the non-zip files using find again, for example : find . -type f ! -name '*.zip' -delete that I found here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78378

Comment: I have a LOT of files, so I'd rather do this in as few operations as possible. Otherwise I would just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-pend a relative path to the location of the zip file as:

```
find . -type f -exec zip -D '../zipdir/{}.zip' '{}' \;
```

If needed, to create the directory structure you can do:

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p '../zipdir/{}' \;
```

Comment: When I try doing this, it gives me errors:


    zip I/O error: No such file or directory
    zip error: Could not create output file (../test1_zipped/./file.zip)

Comment: So I tried creating the top-level directory for the output (test1_zipped/), and it zips each file in the top-level directory that I'm zipping from, but not any files in the sub-directories. Do I need to re-create the entire directory structure in the output directory with this solution? Is there an automated way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not married to zip files, you could just create a squashfs image of the whole directory tree in question that's mountable too (no opening & looking in specific zip files to see what's there). It may have better compression too, since it looks at the entire tree together, more like a "solid" archive, instead of lots of individual zip files.

Basically you just need the `squashfs-tools` package (that's what it's called in Debian/Ubuntu, maybe a different name in different linux families), then:

```
mksquashfs /some/directory  archive.squashfs
```

and to mount/view/browse it:

```
mount archive.squashfs /mnt/mountpoint -t squashfs
```

the -t flag may even be optional, mount is really good at automatically figuring out types. Shouldn't need the `-o loop` flag either, but try it just in case it's needed.

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html or just search for [how to use squashfs](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+use+squashfs).