# Is there a way to make 7z retain the output folder structure rather than putting all files and subfolders into one single .7z file?

Tags: linux, 7-zip

Is there a way to make 7z retain the output folder structure rather than putting all files and subfolders into one single .7z file?

My input is for example:

```
Folder A
File A
File B
File C
Folder B
File BA
File BB
File BC
```

Rather than having everything output to filex.7z I would like the output structure to be the same as above but as separate .7z files. Is it possible?

Vesa

OS: Termux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip multiple files into separate archives?](https://superuser.com/questions/430388/how-to-zip-multiple-files-into-separate-archives)

Comment: It is kind of a duplicate, however, this question is about another tool (7z) which has its share of problems which need to be avoided via extra arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` utility for that:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec p7zip '{}' \;
```

And to decompress:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec p7zip -d '{}' \;
```

`p7zip` is the linux CLI tool for 7z (on Debian-based derivatives).

Comment: Interesting. I will try that as soon as possible. If I want to add flags to the p7zip command where do they go? Inside the brackets or after ?

Comment: @Vesa sorry for late reply. They go before the brackets. Like this: `-exec p7zip -flag '{}' \;` The brackets contain the name of the file from find as a variable.

Comment: Hi. Your first command returns an error message: find: ‘p7zip’: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to install p7zip first @Vesa. What Linux distribution are you on? For Debian/Ubuntu, use `sudo apt-get install p7zip`

Comment: It's installed already. Termux.

Comment: Ok, turns out this works fine with p7zip in another emulator so could be something wrong with the p7zip implementation in the first emulator I tested. One more thing, is it possible to add password and filename encryption too with flas?

Comment: Alternatively could I use 7z instead if p7zip does not support password and encrypted filesnames?

Comment: @Vesa hey, yes you can, check this out - https://www.2daygeek.com/zip-7zip-encrypt-decrypt-password-protect-files-folders-linux/

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to encrypt an archive with 7z. I need to know how to make 7z encrypt the files and folders one by one using find or a similar method. See original question.